I'm using flutter upgrader, in debug messages are being printed but update popup is not appearing
do we really need appcastconfig file for using upgrader
home: UpgradeAlert(
              shouldPopScope: () {
                return true;
              },
              
              upgrader: Upgrader(debugDisplayAlways: true, debugLogging: true, durationUntilAlertAgain: Duration(days: 3)),
              dialogStyle: Platform.isIOS ? UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino : UpgradeDialogStyle.material,
              child: SplashScreen()),

i did this but update popup is not appearing though console are being printed

Update
as the code for upgradeAlert was used on main.dart
due to some asynchronous function and screen rendering based on condition the screen changes within 2 second that prevent the popup from appearing.
i used the upgradeAlert in home when screen become stable and it works perfectly
